# Convert a string into an integer after the line of strings has been split?

Tags: python

```
import math

def main():
    StrFileName = input('Enter a File')
    inFile = open(StrFileName, 'r')
    intLines = 0

    for i in open(StrFileName, 'r'):
        intLines = intLines + 1

    intTotalLines = intLines
    intID = 0
    intAmt = 0
    intIncome = 0
    State = 0

    for i in range(intTotalLines):
        line = inFile.readline()
        intID, intAmt, intIncome, State = line.split()
        Line = [intID, intAmt, intIncome, State]
        Income = int(intIncome)
        print(sum(Income))

main()
```

I keep getting the message `int object is not iterable` when trying to convert `intIncome` into an `int` (the line split automatically makes it a string). Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Your error is from calling `sum` with the argument `Income`. `Income` is already an integer, so just print it:

```
print(Income)
```

Comment: I'd also recommend rewriting it so the file isn't opened twice at one time. I'm really not sure what would happen with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the sum of the incomes from each line, you can either construct a list and sum it, or keep a running total like:

```
totalIncome = 0

for i in range(intTotalLines):

        line = inFile.readline()

        intID, intAmt, intIncome, state = line.split()

        totalIncome += int(intIncome)

print(totalIncome)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    str_file_name = input("Enter a File")
    with open(str_file_name, 'r') as in_file: # use with to open your files as it closes them automatically
        int_lines = 0

        for i in open(str_file_name, 'r'):
            int_lines += 1
        int_total_lines = int_lines

        for i in range(int_total_lines):
            lines = in_file.readline()
            int_id, int_amt, int_income, state = lines.split()
            income = int(int_income)
            print(income)
main()
```

I edited your code with examples of how variables should be named, you should not use uppercase for variable names, `int_lines += 1` is shorthand for `int_lines = int_lines + 1`.

I removed some variables that were not being used, but I just wanted to show you a few styling tips to make your code a bit more readable and in line with the [python style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)